# Getting Started with ServiceStack on OSX

Tags: macos, monodevelop, servicestack

I cloned the example on my Mac and right out of the gate there are several projects that won't build. Specifically trying to build the MovieRest example I get the error:

Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider' from`ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0584) (ServiceStack.MovieRest)

I cannot find any help or example on getting started with ServiceStack on the Mac which I find really odd because they make a really hard for using MonoDevelop in their overview presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Example projects were upgraded to reference NuGet packages but the MovieRest project didn't reference the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono) NuGet package (so they were out-of-sync). I've just done this and have checked it in now.

Since I did this with VS.NET 2012 here the VS.NET Solution file was also upgraded so you will need the latest MonoDevelop (3.1.1) on their Beta channel to open.

Note: All example projects were **developed in VS.NET** but are **deployed** on Mono/Linux when hosted on servicestack.net which is an Hetzner Ubuntu vServer. We don't care as much about developing in MonoDevelop as we do about running your ServiceStack-based software on Linux/Mono hosts. Ideally it should do both, but as we develop primarily in VS.NET we're not constantly testing against MonoDevelop.

#### Sqlite on Windows vs Mono + Linux / OSX

Sqlite is an unmanaged native C library which unlike the rest of .NET can't run the same binary on multiple platforms.

When using .NET on windows, the `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite` package references `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll` which for Windows/.NET will use the unmanaged `sqlite3.dll` in `bin/` folder (which is why sqlite.dll needs to be set as a Content resource that's set to Copy if Newer). For Linux it looks for **sqlite3.so** whilst on OSX it looks for **libsqlite3.dylib** in your Library lookup path. If you have Sqlite installed in your host OS it will find these automatically, if it doesn't you will need to include a path to these shared libraries in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.